# iOS apps for sync data via sftp

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, data-synchronization, sftp

Please give me advice with iOS apps for data sync via sftp. I've tried using google... But there is no result.
I need to sync iOS 8.1 with debian via sftp in live mode.

Comment: `Secure Shellfish`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you meant with "sync via sftp", but if you just need an ftp client, you could use [Transmit](https://panic.com/transmit-ios/), that is available for iPhone and iPad and support the following protocols:

- FTP
- FTP with TLS/SSL
- FTP with implicit TLS/SSL
- SFTP
- WebDAV
- WebDAV HTTPS
- Amazon S3
- DreamObjects